# Cannot send mail with attachment from web

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, stream

I need to download a text file from web and attach it to a mail before sending it out. Below is what I have done but it throws exception `Failure sending mail. The request was aborded'

```
WebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create("http://samplesite/sampletext.txt"));
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin");
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(responseStream, dictIterator.Key)); //on commenting this, it  works fine
}
client.Send(msg);  //throws exception
```

Im sure that it is something to do with the attachment as commenting it makes it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are disposing your response object before reading and using it from its stream. I've not tested the code but this is the simple idea how to work with it:

```
byte[] myResponse;
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    myResponse = ReadFully(responseStream);//done with the stream now and dispose it
    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myResponse), dictIterator.Key));
}
client.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
SmtpClient client=new SmtpClient( );
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        client.Host = "yourHost";
        msg.From =new MailAddress( "adress-from");
        msg.To.Add( new MailAddress("adress-to"  ));
        msg.Subject = "your subject";
        msg.Body="your message";

        System.Net.WebRequest myrequest;
        System.Net.WebResponse myresponse;
        System.IO.Stream s;

        string url = "your url to the file";
        myrequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        myresponse = myrequest.GetResponse();

        s = myresponse.GetResponseStream();

        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment( s,System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));


        client.Send(msg);
```